# Get Boolean Value from VM Parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, idioms

How do I elegantly get a Boolean value from a VM parameter? My solution is not as easy as I

1. have to test if it is null otherwise I will get
   IllegalArgumentException
2. have to convert the entire String to upper or lower case and test if
       it is exactly "false" or "true" otherwise I will have the same
       exception thrown at my face.

i.e.

```
    val property = System.getProperty("some.property.name")
    property != null && property.toLowerCase == "true"
```

Is there another way out of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala has the `sys.props` object which wraps the Java system properties API, so you can deal with `Option` instead of `null`.

```
sys.props.get("property.name") exists (_ equalsIgnoreCase "true")
```

Answer (score 3):

[`java.lang.Boolean#getBoolean(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) does exactly what you are looking for, if you are not against calling into Java API classes:

```
scala> import java.lang.Boolean
import java.lang.Boolean

scala> Boolean.getBoolean("some.property.name")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> System.setProperty("foo", "true")
res1: String = null

scala> Boolean.getBoolean("foo")
res2: Boolean = true

scala> System.setProperty("bar", "false")
res3: String = null

scala> Boolean.getBoolean("bar")
res4: Boolean = false

scala> System.setProperty("baz", "lorem ipsum")
res5: String = null

scala> Boolean.getBoolean("baz")
res6: Boolean = false
```

Comment: There are differences between Scala's Boolean and java.lang.Boolean. I prefer not to import them unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> "true" equalsIgnoreCase "TruE"
res0: Boolean = true

scala> "true" equalsIgnoreCase System.getProperty("does.not.exist")
res1: Boolean = false
```